# Custom Gif loader in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

How to use custom .gif file preloader in custom UI5 application. When clicking a button for popup or navigation delay.

Below is my code

```
<content>
        <Button
            text="Dialog"
            width="230px"
            press="onDialogPress"
            class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom" />
    </content>

onDialogPress: function(oEvent) {

    var that = this;
    if (!that.pressDialog) {
        that.pressDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog({
            text: 'Loading...',
        });

        //to get access to the global model
        this.getView().addDependent(that.pressDialog);
    }

    that.pressDialog.open();
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [BusyDialog](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.BusyDialog.html#constructor) has the option to add the custom Image:

```
onDialogPress: function(oEvent) {
    if (!this.pressDialog) {
        this.pressDialog = new sap.m.BusyDialog({
            text: 'Loading...',
            customIcon: './stackoverflow/loading.gif',
            customIconRotationSpeed: 0,
            customIconWidth: '48px',
            customIconHeight: '48px'
        });
        this.getView().addDependent(that.pressDialog);
    }
    this.pressDialog.open();
}
```

Result:
[image]